# ElasticSearch 2.x GeoPoint mapping with NEST C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net, elasticsearch-2.0

Im having a problem mapping "Geo Point" in elasticsearch using NEST C# Client.

Here is my class definition:

```
 [GeoPoint(Name = "coordinates", LatLon = true)]
  public Coordinates Coordinates { get; set; }

 public class Coordinates
 {
    [Number(NumberType.Double, Name = "lat")]
    public double Lat { get; set; }

    [Number(NumberType.Double, Name = "lng")]
    public double Lng { get; set; }
 }
```

My mapping properties on Index creation:

```
.Mappings(map => map
    .Map<Crime>(m => m.AutoMap()
    .TimestampField(ts => ts.Enabled(true).Path("timeStamp"))                                                
    .Properties(pro => pro
      .GeoPoint(geo => geo
         .Name(n => n.Coordinates)
         .LatLon(true)
))))
```

And my mapping doesnt look right once some documents were indexed....

```
...
"coordinates": {
                  "properties": {
                     "lat": {
                        "type": "double"
                     },
                     "lng": {
                        "type": "double"
                     }
                  }
               },
...
```

And when i try querying it (using SENSE) I get the following error:

```
"reason": {
               "type": "query_parsing_exception",
               "reason": "failed to parse [geo_bbox] query. could not find [geo_point] field [coordinates]",
               "index": "someindexname",
               "line": 16,
               "col": 9
            }
```

So in my opinion the problem is with my mapping, but everything has changed quite drastically in 2.x update (compared to 1.x) that I dont know how to map a geo point properly. Any Ideas ?

Comment: Are you testing this against ES 2.x?

Comment: @Rob yeah... I did mention this in my second last sentence, but Youre right - I should make it more explicit..Oh wait - it says 2.x in the title :)

Comment: Oh right, sorry for that :)

Comment: but you are using NEST v2, right? :)

Comment: Maybe you were trying other mapping earlier and you didn't remove index before applying new mapping?

Comment: Yes and Yes, creating new indices and mapping with Elasticsearch.net 2.1.0 and NEST 2.1.0

Comment: You need to remove index if you want to change mapping. More details in [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime) great article.

Comment: Im creating new indices....

Comment: I think you have a typo in the fluent mapping - `Coordinatesm`

Comment: Sorry, thats me trying to indent stuff properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved - updated NEST library to the newest release -

And also renamed my Coordinates class member Lng to Lon:

```
[Number(NumberType.Double, Name = "lon")]
public double Lon { get; set; }
```

I think the C# declaration doesnt matter its just the annotation thats important.

Thanks